# json encoding for unicode text in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, unicode

I have created an array in my codeigniter controller and encoded as json  as follows :

```
$templateText = $this->input->post('sampletext');
$template_sample = $this->input->post('sampletext');
$postdata = array('userid'          => LOGIN_FOR_TEMPLATE,
                    'password'          => PASWD_FOR_TEMPLATE,
                    'template'          => $templateText,
                    'template_sample'   => $template_sample,
                    'callback_url'      => base_url().'API/templateCallback'
                ); 

$postdata = json_encode($postdata); 
print_r($postdata);
```

if the `$templateText` is a unicode string, then the array is not encoded properly.

To test this I set this variable as :

```
$templateText = 'नये ऑफर 123';
$template_sample = 'नये ऑफर 123';
```

but my print_r() function display details as follows :

`{"userid":"xxxx","password":"xxxx","template":"\u0928\u092f\u0947 \u0911\u092b\u0930 123","template_sample":"\u0928\u092f\u0947 \u0911\u092b\u0930 123","callback_url":"http:\/\/example.com\/API\/templateCallback"}`

But I need to set it as `'नये ऑफर 123`
like :

```
{"userid":"xxxx","password":"xxxx","template":"नये ऑफर 123","template_sample":"नये ऑफर 123","callback_url":"http://example.com/API/templateCallback"}
```

How do I solve this

I already set `<meta charset="utf-8">` in my html

Comment: That's a fairly strange need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it as

```
$postdata = json_encode($postdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

You can use it as below for your URL

```
$postdata = json_encode($postdata,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: I need one more help. how can i set url like `"callback_url":"http://example.com/API/templateCallback"` in this json